# Langs Algebra, module isomorphsim, alternate proof, p644

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, modules

> Let $E$ be simple $R$-module, suppose exists $n,m$ positive integers, $E^{(n)} \stackrel{\phi}{\cong} E^{(m)}$ (as $R$-modules) then $n=m$.

The way Lang does it is by saying

> $M_n(End_{R}(E)) \cong End_{R}(E^{(n)})=End_{R}(E^{(m)}) \cong M_m(End_{R}(E))$. Noting that $End_{R}(E)$ is a division ring, and dimension is well defined.

I was thinking of the following: Lable LHS, RHS by $E_1,\ldots, E_n$. wlog, $n>m$.

> 1. $\phi_{ij}:=\pi_j \circ \phi \circ j_i:E_i \rightarrow E_j$ is either $0$ or isomoprhism from Schur's lemma.  $j_i, \pi_j$ are the inclusion and projection maps respectively.
> 2. As $\phi$ is iso, must exists $j$ such that $\phi_{ij}$ is an iso. By pigeonhole princple, exists $1 \le i \not=l \le n$, such that $E_i$, $E_l$ have image on $E_j$ under $\phi$.
> 3. $\phi$ is not injective. Contradiction. $n \le m$. By symmetry, $n=m$.

I wonder if this is a valid proof.

Comment: I don't see 2. In general the image of each $E_i$ won't be a summand $E_j$.

Comment: Ah you are right...

Answer (score 1):

Your way is not valid.  You can't apply the pigeonhole principle because $E^{(n)}$ generally has more than $n$ simple submodules.  (It's just that only $n$ of them appear in any given decomposition, but that's not enough.)

Lang's proof appears to be valid, but to my mind it seems an odd way to prove a special case of the Krull-Schmidt theorem.

Comment: I agree. But I think Lord Shark The Unknown as pointed out the actual mistake.